# Overriding OnMeasure

Tags: android, layout, view, android-custom-view, onmeasure

I made a custom view with the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/packetlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000FF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tempEdit"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view2"
    android:text="Temp : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tempEdit"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drawingCanvas"
    android:ems="5"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tempEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="5"
    android:text="115"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/timeEdit"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeEdit"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/drawingCanvas"
    android:text="Time : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawingCanvas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeEdit"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tempEdit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

i want to insert multiple duplicate of them into a ScrollView with a Linearlayout.

Due to different screen size i understand that we have to scale them accordingly using the onmeasure override.

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // get width and height size and mode
    int wSpec = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int hSpec = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int hMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = wSpec;
    int height = hSpec;

    // ideal height for the number display
    int idealHeight = (int) (wSpec * 1);

    if(idealHeight < hSpec)
    {
        height = idealHeight;
    }

    Log.e("logging " , wSpec + "   " + hSpec + "   " + hMode + "   " + width + "  " + height);
    setMeasuredDimension(wSpec / 2, hSpec/2);
}
```

Using the code above i always obtain a wSpec  = 0 and hSpec = 382.

How can i obtain the size of the LinearLayout of which i want to insert my CustomView into ?

Thanks

Comment: Usually a widthSpec of 0 means that the mode is UNSPECIFIED which means the child is responsible for measuring itself.  This usually is the case with limitless Views like ScrollView (though in the case of width, it would be HorizontalScrollView)